# Strange Pipe Values when calling pipe()

Tags: c

so I seem to have a strange bug of sorts.

The project I'm currently working asks me to spawn a number of child process, each of them calculating the average of the other child processes around them, then reporting back to the parent via a common pipe what that child's average is.

After I call pipe() a fifth time in the parent process to open up file descriptors 11 and 12, I seem to get those values, as well as the values 3 and 6. Any idea why this is the case? I only close file descriptors within child process, and before the parent process is about to exit.

Code for this specific process :

```
pipe(parentPipe); //opens FDs 3,4
.... //code that spawns 2 or 3 children, depending on input
if (children == 4) {
   pipe(leftIn); //opens FDs 5,6
   if (!fork()) {
      //In the left most child
      close(parentPipe[0]);
      close(leftIn[0]);
      OneCell(...) //just makes a child
   }
   //Two more pipes for communication between current child and next
   pipe(rightIn); //opens 7,8
   pipe(rightOut); //opens 9,10
   if (!fork()) {
      close(parentPipe[0]); 
      close(leftIn[1]); 
      close(rightIn[1]); 
      close(rightOut[0]);
      EndAdjCells(...)
   }
   pipe(leftOut); <-- this is the pipe that gives me strange values 
   printf("Leftout FDs Read %d Write: %d\n", leftOut[0], leftOut[1]);
```

The printf after pipe(leftOut) appears twice in my console. Once with the values of 11 and 12, and then another time it prints 3 and 6.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  For a question like this, you need to show the code you've got.  There's essentially no way to help you without seeing the code.  A single call to `pipe()` only returns two numbers; it is not clear how you might get 11, 12, 3 and 6 from a single call.

Comment: Apologies. Added code for clarity.

Comment: Do `OneCell` and `EndAdjCells` return? If so it seems you are not correctly delimiting the child and parent code. The code after each of the `if` blocks that call `fork` are executed by both parent and child processes (assuming that those two functions mentioned do return).

Comment: The functions don't return, they exec() another process. The parameters of those two functions are commandline arguments for the process to be exec'd. If it's helpful, I can add the function parameters into the question.

Comment: So then are you sure that the `exec` calls did indeed succeed? Because it seems you do not check the return code of most of the function calls.

Comment: You were right - my exec call in EndAdjCells was wonky. Thank you.